# Community page not loading after changing language to Chinese (Simplified)

Tags: lightning, community, button, language

I encountered the case that after changing language for community user to Chinese (Simplified) and login to community for the first time, I get 404 page ("Page not available"), after refresh and for further logins this is not happen.
I investigated that when I replace  with  this issue doesn't occur.

Do anybody faced such issue or have any idea what could cause that?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE. Do you have the same problem if you create the user to begin with using Chinese (Simplified)? What language did you change this user from before moving them to Chinese? This sounds to me like it might be a "cookie" issue or browser caching issue. If the problem doesn't exist when creating them originally in Chinese (Simplified), I wouldn't worry about it. If converting from one version of Chinese to another, then you have a different situation.

Comment: Hi, the problem doesn't happen when I begin with Chinese(Simplified), only when I change it from English -> Chinese, so accourding to your assumption it would be related to browser cookie issue.